# LOG4J json-template-layout - Adding all headers

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I've been trying to add http headers under a header object and I cant seem to get it working how I want it to with the json  template layout. The below method works, but it also adds all elements in the MDC.

```json
  "headers": {
    "$resolver": "mdc",
  },
```

```java
ThreadContext.put("Host", request.getRemoteHost);
ThreadContext.put("Method", request.getMethod);
```

I can see in the docs that  [LOG4J Map Resolver Template](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html#map-resolver-template) but I  cant figure out how  to use it. It looks like it referencing an object, but I cant pass an object to the TheadContext?

Desired output

```json
{
 "timestamp": "2023-10-27T17:00:00.000Z",
 "level" "INFO",
 "headers" : {
    "host": "localhost",
    "method": "POST"
 },
 "logger": "my_logger"
}
```

I can create a MapMessage and parse it to the log()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following template should get the job done:

```
{
  "timestamp": {
    "$resolver": "timestamp",,
    "pattern": {
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
  },
  "level": {
    "$resolver": "level",
    "field": "name"
  },
  "headers": {
    "host": {
      "$resolver": "mdc",
      "key": "Host"
    },
    "method": {
      "$resolver": "mdc",
      "key": "Method"
    }
  },
  "logger": {
    "$resolver": "logger",
    "field": "name"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Volkan.  This is great and is working as required. Thanks for your help :)